# Why is FreeBSD rebooting during installation?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, reboot

I have a samsung laptop which is around 1.5 years old. I am currently running arch linux and have run various linux distributions successfully in the past.

The hardware is not obsolete and the processor architecture is amd64. I always ran the precompiled version of linux kernel, so I don't think that I have a hardware problem

Now, when I try to install FreeBSD-10.0 release for amd64 on my laptop, after the kernel loads (during the installation procedure) the laptop reboots automatically.

Can someone tell me what can be the possible reasons/solutions to this problem?

Comment: If possible, could you please post a picture of you screen if an error message exists? Also, what is the notebook model? I can see a wide range o problemas that will be reduced only with more info ;)

Comment: I don't have a picture, and there is no error message involved. It just reboots after some time. I can't figure out which stage is failing during boot time.  The notebook model is NP-305E5A.

Comment: Have you tried 10.1?

Comment: Possibly UEFI related but I can't help beyond that

Answer (score 0):

Start from disabling ACPI, if will not help - try 'Safe Mode'
https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-start.html#bsdinstall-boot-options-menu

If you wouldn't be able to boot even with safe mode (what is common for FreeBSD on laptops) - please post dmesg output from linux here.