# FreeBSD 11.1 install fails and reboot

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to install FreeBSD 11.1 on AMD based board. But installation fails and the system reboots. This happens repeatedly.

Here is what I am doing:

1. I have created a bootable USB media with 11.1 memstick image (checksum verified)
2. I chose USB as my first boot device in my BIOS (Aptio v2.18 - UEFI based)
3. I see the FreeBSD boot loader menu (giving options for multi user,single user etc.,)
4. I chose multi-user boot.  I see the hardware probe is starting and shortly after that system reboots before I get the "Welcome menu"(which will have the install option). I see a trace flashing before the system reboots (but couldn't capture it).

Note:  I see the same behaviour when I try with single user mode (or) safe boot "on". I don't see the option for "ACPI support" in "Boot options menu". So, I assume it's disabled already.

Questions:

1. Could this be related to BIOS? If so, how?  I tried with 10.4 UEFI memstick image also. Same behaviour seen
2. Is there any way I can capture the hardware probe logs to a file (because it just flashes and reboots) (other than serial console)
3. Is there any way I can prevent rebooting (if there is a panic) from boot loader prompt? I tried boot_pause set to 1.  But when I continue booting, system hangs.

I see [a similar issue reported here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193853/why-is-freebsd-rebooting-during-installation) but the suggested solution doesn't help my case.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , See this recommendation on [FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-install-trouble.html)

Comment: @GAD3R Thanks for your reply. I had attempted that solution to set hint.acpi.0.disabled=1.  When I do, it panics saying "running without a device atpic requires a local APIC". 

From [link](http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/01/freebsd-running-without-device-atpic.html)

I understand apic is enabled by default in amd64(in GENERIC). I am trying the 11.1 released image only. So, i believe apic should be there, but it's not the case. So, confused about this solution.

Comment: FreeBSD forums may be a better venue for asking these questions. Have you tried asking there? Also, AMD based board is a very general term, what is your specific hardware configuration?

Comment: @ajeh:  Yes, I have a FreeBSD forum post as well for this issue.

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/freebsd-11-1-installation-fails-and-rebooting.65814/